# Define quaternions by properties instead of coordinates

Tags: expression-manipulation, algebra, quaternions

I'd like to manipulate an expression of quaternions and only use the following properties

```
q1+q2=q2+q1
q1**(q2+q3)=q1**q2+q1**q3
q1**(q2**q3)=(q1**q2)**q3
Conjugate[q1**q2]=Conjugate[q2]**Conjugate[q1]
q**x=x**q if x is Real
q**Conjugate[q] is always Real
Conjugate[x]=x if x is Real
```

Comment: Do you want to set up an algebra for quaternions? So that you can manipulate them. Or prove statements about them in general.

Comment: Yes I want to set up an algebra